# The logic between multiple comparison in SAS

Tags: compare, sas

```
data test; set A;
  if a1--a21>0 then b=0;
  else b=1;
run;
```

Does anyone know if "a1--a21>0" implies a1>0 and a2>0 and....a21>0 ?
If not, how can I express  a1>0 and a2>0 and....a21>0? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution would be to use the MIN function with OF, which enables reading across variables similar to an array.  Notice that I have changed a1--a21 to a1-21.  It's a subtle difference, a1--a21 says use all variables that occur physically between a1 and a21, whereas a1-a21 says use variables a1,a2,a3,...,a21.  It is probably the same in most table structures, but using a single - is safer in this example.
The only thing to be wary of is whether you have missing values, these won't be taken into account with my solution.

```
data test; set A;
  if min(of a1-a21)>0 then b=0;
  else b=1;
run;
```

Comment: if min(of a1-a21) >0 and nmiss(of a1-a21) = 0 then b=0; etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do what you are trying.  I always do this with an array.

```
data test;
a1 = 1;
a2 = 0;
a3 = 1;
array a[3];
ok = 1;
do i=1 to 3;
    ok = ok and a[i]>0;
end;
if ok then put "YES";
else put "NO";
run;
```

Changing the value of a2 shows this works.